# IIS conflict with Sql Server Reporting Services 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7, windows-server-2008

When running in Visual Studio, my mvc3 app does not ask for any authentication. However, when I deployed to test server (Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7) I keep getting a prompt asking for UserName and Password. I supply the admin credentials for the server yet there is a failure. The strange thing is that the page is served but I keep getting the prompt. All the ajax calls however fail with a 401 Unauthorized error.

I tried different types of authentication but the results are the same. Even with anonymous authentication only I get a prompt for user name and password.

I tried changing the pipeline from Managed to Classic but then MVC would not work and I get 404 error. This is my first mvc app and I did not expect such issues in deployment.

Any clues how to get this to work?

==Edit begin=== 
This is what I suspect might be causing the issue. On the server the site is bound to test.xyz.com. Also, there is Sql Server Reporting Services Installed. My application is tries to query the url test.xyz.com/Reports but I think this is bound to SSRS. When I stop the SSRS service I get a service unavailable 503 error. Otherwise I get a authentication window.

I am trying to find out how can I remove the particular SSRS binding so that test.xyz.com/Reports points to my Reports Controller
==Edit end====

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my controller from Reports to MyReports and this resolved the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Reporting Services Configuration Manager to specify the port and url that Reporting Services uses on the server.

By default SQL Server Reporting Services uses the following urls:

```
http://<server name>/ReportServer // web service url

http://<server name>/reports // reports manager url
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- Does your web application accessing any resources? If so, does the IIs worker process account have permission to those?
- Have you set the Web Site Authentication to `Enable anonymous access`?
- Do you by any chance doing impersonation (either in web.config of programmatically? If so, does the end user account have the proper permissions to any eventual back end resources?